# valid string in vim?

Tags: vim

Handy shortcut "*" - which reads the "string" under the cursor and goes to the next place it appears.

can some one clarify what comprises a valid "string" in vim. 
I am facing a problem that when i use "*" with cursor on word "function" on the following line  
function(val) {}

it selects the text "function(val)" and searches for that but i am interested only in search for "function" alone. It considering parentheses also as a valid character in a string.

I see this behavior randomly and want to understand what comprises a valid "string" in vim and is it configurable like "isfname" option which specifies the list of characters that can appear in a file name.

Thanks in advance, 
Naga Kiran

Comment: "string" is just a synonymous term to "word" in vim. So, the definition of "word" in vim applies to "string".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the setting involved is `iskeyword`, which follows the same syntax as `isfname`. On my gvim on Windows XP it is set to

```
  iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255
```

and I don't observe the behavior that you describe. See `:help iskeyword` and `:help isfname` for further information.